# javascript if/else statement works for first two statements but stops on the third?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have attempted to change this in several different ways ( `if (currentView === theCube[x])` ) tried to iterate over it with a while statement.  But the method I have used below works fine for the first two rounds but then stops functioning on the last round. I have taken it to Code pen and consoled out the value of `currentView` and it does increase as it should, but the grid does not change colors (to white) as it was in previous.

[Here is code pen of the project](https://codepen.io/url54/pen/RwLZLVE?editors=1111)

Snippet also below:

```js
const topMoveBtn = document.getElementById('topMoveBtn')
const rightMoveBtn = document.getElementById('rightMoveBtn')
const leftMoveBtn = document.getElementById('leftMoveBtn')
const botMoveBtn = document.getElementById('botMoveBtn')
const grid = document.getElementById('grid-container')
let x = 0
let y = 0
let squares = []
let frontView = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
let bottomView = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
let backView = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
let topView = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
let leftView = [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
let rightView = [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
let currentView = frontView
let theCube = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
  [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
  [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
  [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
]
/* Color Mappings:
  0 = Red,
  1 = Yellow,
  2 = Orange,
  3 = White,
  4 = Green,
  5 = Blue
*/
topMoveBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (x === 0) {
    x++
    currentView = theCube[x]
    makeGrid()
  } else if (x === 1) {
    x++
    currentView = theCube[x]
    makeGrid()
  } else if (x === 2) {
    x++
    currentView = theCube[x]
    makeGrid()
  } else if (x === 3) {
    return x = 0
  }
})


function makeGrid() {
  for (let i = 0; i < currentView.length; i++) {
    const square = document.createElement('div')
    grid.appendChild(square)
    squares.push(square)

    if (currentView[i] === 0) {
      squares[i].classList.add('squareR')
    } else if (currentView[i] === 1) {
      squares[i].classList.add('squareY')
    } else if (currentView[i] === 2) {
      squares[i].classList.add('squareO')
    } else if (currentView[i] === 3) {
      squares[i].classList.add('squareW')
    } else if (currentView[i] === 4) {
      squares[i].classList.add('squareG')
    } else if (currentView[i] === 5) {
      squares[i].classList.add('squareB')
    }
  }
}
makeGrid()
```

```css
body {
  min-width: 800px;
}

button {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 20px;
  transform: scale(1.3);
  border: none;
}

header {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.all-view-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.bottom-move-container,
.top-move-container,
.left-move-container,
.right-move-container,
.middle-container,
.bottom-button-container,
.top-button-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.left-middle-button,
.right-middle-button {
  margin-top: 110px;
  margin-bottom: 110px;
}

.left-top-button,
.right-top-button {
  margin-top: 45px;
}

.top-middle-button,
.bottom-middle-button {
  margin-left: 105px;
  margin-right: 105px;
}

.left-move-button,
.right-move-button {
  margin-top: 105px;
  height: 200px;
}

.top-move-button,
.bottom-move-button {
  width: 200px;
  border: visible;
}

.bottom-move-button {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border: visible;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 140px 140px 140px;
  grid-template-columns: 140px 140px 140px;
}

.mini-grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 80px 80px 80px;
  grid-template-columns: 80px 80px 80px;
}

.squareR,
.squareY,
.squareW,
.squareG,
.squareB,
.squareO {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.squareR {
  background: red;
}

.squareY {
  background: yellow;
}

.squareW {
  background: white;
}

.squareG {
  background: green;
}

.squareB {
  background: blue;
}

.squareO {
  background: orange;
}

.whole-container {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="whole-container">
    <!-- Whole Container -->

    <div class="top-container">
      <!-- Top-section Container (will be in 2 rows) -->
      <div>
        <div class="top-move-container">
          <!-- move to Top Container -->
          <button id="topMoveBtn" class="top-move-button">⏫</button>
        </div>
        <div class="top-button-container">
          <!-- Top Button Container -->
          <button id="topLeftBtn"></button><button id="topMidBtn" class="top-middle-button"></button><button id="topRightBtn"></button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- End of Top Container -->

    <div class="middle-container">
      <!-- Middle Section Container (will be in 5 columns) -->
      <div>
        <div class="left-move-container">
          <!-- move to Left Container -->
          <button id="leftMoveBtn" class="left-move-button">⏪</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="left-button-container">
        <!-- Left Button Container -->
        <div>
          <button id="leftTopBtn" class="left-top-button">◀️</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button id="leftMidBtn" class="left-middle-button">◀️</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button id="leftBotBtn">◀️</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Grid for game -->
      <div class="grid-container" id="grid-container">

      </div>
      <!-- Grid for game -->

      <div class="right-button-container">
        <!-- Right Button Container -->
        <div>
          <button id="rightTopBtn" class="right-top-button">▶️</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button id="RightMidBtn" class="right-middle-button">▶️</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button id="RightBotBtn">▶️</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="right-move-container">
        <!-- move to Right Container -->
        <button id="rightMoveBtn" class="right-move-button">⏩</button>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="bottom-container">
      <!-- Bottom Section Container (will be in 2 rows (like top-container)) -->

      <div class="bottom-button-container">
        <!-- Bottom Button Container -->
        <button id="botLeftBtn"></button><button id="botMidBtn" class="bottom-middle-button"></button><button id="botRightBtn"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom-move-container">
        <!-- move to bottom Container -->
        <button id="botMoveBtn" class="bottom-move-button">⏬</button>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- End of Bottom Container -->

  </div>
  <!-- End of Whole Container -->

  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why did you not do `if (x < 3) {} else {}`

Comment: Dude, noone's gonna read all that, provide minimum code, so one can help you out!

Comment: @Deadpool sorry, I added the snippet. It was just a wall of JS before.

Comment: @epascarello I am new to JS and didn't think about that lol, sorry.

Comment: @Deadpool This is the 2nd all-time post I apologize for blasting your screen

Comment: @RandyCasburn I'm thinking I messed up on my counting >< thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you keep adding classes. You never remove the old classes.

First
"class1"

Second:
"class1 class2"

Third call
"class1 class2 class3"

You need to remove the other classes

```
 squares[i].classList.remove('squareR', 'squareY', 'squareO');
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Removing the extra classes stopped the sticking point.

Answer (score 0):

I put a `console.log` statement inside the `else if (x === 3)` like so:

```
else if (x === 3) {
    console.log(x)
    return x = 0
  }
```

I was able to see x logged out in the console. This seems to be reaching the third statement.